# Get IMEI of an android phone on page load

Tags: android, jquery, cordova-plugins

I am developing an application in Cordova which requires to get the IMEI number of any device programatically. I want want get the IMEI on page load and store it on local storage

```
 $(function(){

       $('#LoginForm').submit(function(){

        var loginData = $ ("#LoginForm").serialize();
         $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        data: loginData,
        crossDomian: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.cMessage.code)
        if(data.cMessage.code == "0"){

             window.location.href = "Home.html"
            }

           else{
                window.location.href = "Payment.html"

            }
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);

    });


            return false;});
   })
```

Comment: your app will be removed from playstore if found misusing the IMEI. IMEI and other device specific data comes under user privacy and must be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a unique number to identify the device, then you can use this:

android.os.Build.SERIAL;

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the cordova plugin [device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/) to optain the unique identifier of any cordova supported OS.

```
//Get the device's Universally Unique Identifier
var string = device.uuid;
```